# What TeXBook version has built-in bookmarks?

Tags: bookmarks, books, ctan, tutorials, ebook

My PDF copy of the TeXbook, surprisingly, doesn't contain any built-in bookmark. Do you know what version has them?

Comment: Your PDF copy of the TeXbook is also probably missing the illustrations by Duane Bibby. In other words, it is *not* a PDF copy of the TeXbook at all, but the result of tex-ing `texbook.tex` which was provided only for study, not for running through TeX, and does not even produce something identical to the (print) *TeXbook*.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR if possible, can you show me some missing pieces, like the illustrations?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That is not CTAN and the pdf copy is illegal. As Knuth says on [his webpage](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~knuth/abcde.html#texbk)

> The source file texbook.tex for The TeXbook has been available for
>   many years, and it begins with the following lines:
>
> ```
>     % This manual is copyright (C) 1984 by the American Mathematical Society.
>     % All rights are reserved!
>     % The file is distributed only for people to see its examples of TeX input,
>     % not for use in the preparation of books like The TeXbook.
>     % Permission for any other use of this file must be obtained in writing
>     % from the copyright holder and also from the publisher (Addison-Wesley).
>     \loop\iftrue
>     \errmessage{This manual is copyrighted and should not be TeXed}\repeat
> ```
>
> From time to time, however, people have flagrantly violated these
>   instructions, and posted PDF files of The TeXbook on the Internet.
>
> Which of the words in those perfectly clear instructions do the people
>   who do such things fail to understand? Please, if you happen to see
>   illicit copies of these books, send a note to board@tug.org so that
>   our user community can apply peer pressure and/or legal action to
>   those who are unfairly exploiting our open-TeX approach.

Having said that, no pdf version is available legally (let alone a built-in bookmark one)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71446/discussion-on-answer-by-caz-sandison-what-texbook-version-has-built-in-bookmarks).